# section a pandas dataframe into 'chunks' based on column value

Tags: python, pandas

The best way to explain what Im trying to accomplish is probably just an example. Given the following dataFrame:

```
     tag  ID
0     0   1
1     0   2
2     1   3
3     1   4
4     0   5
5     1   6
6     0   7
7     0   8
8     1   9
9     1  10
10    0  11
11    0  12
12    0  13
13    1  14
14    1  15
15    1  16
16    0  17
```

Based on the tag, section the dataFrame into 'chunks'. When a chunk is identified, it is stored in a separate dataFrame (or maybe a list of dataFrames?). The criteria for 'chunking' would be to look for 2 or more zeros in the tag column. If there is more than 2 zeros, then section out
all of the data existing between the previous zeros, and the current zeros.

In my example dataFrame above, the code would get rid of the rows indexed: 0,1,6,7,10,11,12...then it would store the following chunks into separate dataFrames:

```
     tag  ID
2     1   3
3     1   4
4     0   5
5     1   6

     tag  ID
8     1   9
9     1  10

     tag  ID
13    1  14
14    1  15
15    1  16
16    0  17
```

I hope its clear. Apologies if not...
Is there a good pythonic way to accomplish this without creating a huge mess of loops?

Thanks for the help,
CJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Already try my best ...I am using two more new parameters

```
df['group']=df.tag.diff().fillna(0).ne(0).cumsum()
df1=df.groupby('group').tag.agg([sum,lambda x : len(x)])
dropindex=df1[(df1['sum']==0)&(df1['<lambda>']>1)].index # only drop more than one continue 0 
df=df.loc[~df.group.isin(dropindex)]
df['group2']=df.reset_index()['index'].diff().ne(1).cumsum().values
for _, dfyourneed in df.groupby('group2',as_index=False):
    print(dfyourneed.drop(['group2','group'],1))

   tag  ID
2    1   3
3    1   4
4    0   5
5    1   6
   tag  ID
8    1   9
9    1  10
    tag  ID
13    1  14
14    1  15
15    1  16
16    0  17
```

Or you can save it into list

```
[dfyourneed.drop(['group2', 'group'], 1) for _, dfyourneed in df.groupby('group2', as_index=False)]
Out[1083]: 
[   tag  ID
 2    1   3
 3    1   4
 4    0   5
 5    1   6,    tag  ID
 8    1   9
 9    1  10,     tag  ID
 13    1  14
 14    1  15
 15    1  16
 16    0  17]
```

Comment: @piRSquared,That is super close! The only problem is that we threw out the rows with only one zero. Im liking to keep row 4 in the first group, and row16 in the ast group, because they only have one zero.

Comment: @cmj29607 ok：-） let us waiting for his answer:-)

Comment: @ Wen. cant say I can totally understand your answer... yet, I'll have to analyze what you did closer. What I do notice is that this is easy to generalize to any number of zeros for the definition of a chunk. df1['<lambda>']>n). very nice :) ty!

Comment: @cmj29607 I break the steps down , each step represent one conversion, if you have any question about it , free to let me know,  I am here to help  :) btw you have 15 rep , you can upvote ~

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I tried,
Create df_new by excluding rows with two or more zeros.

```
df_new = df[(df.tag + df.tag.shift() != 0) & (df.tag + df.tag.shift(-1) != 0)]
```

Create a numpy array of the indices of df_new and split it based on continuous values

```
a = np.array(df_new.index.tolist())
l = np.split(a, np.where(np.diff(a) != 1)[0]+1)
```

Create a list of df using list comprehension on indices

```
df_list = [df.iloc[i] for i in l]
```

To access the dataframes, use

```
df_list[0]

    tag ID
2   1   3
3   1   4
4   0   5
5   1   6
```

Comment: thank you! Your answer is very compact :) I have a hard time to know how I would use *.shift to generalize the chunk criteria. For example, if want the chunk boundary to be defined by a large number of zeros...

Comment: Yeah, but this would be very fast:) The current solution would handle  two or more zeros